# Bluetooth GATT UUID

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, gatt

I'm trying to build an android app that uses the BluetoothLE. In tutorials they use a 128bit UUID but I only have the 16 bit UUID.
I have to create a new 128 bit UUID using the service UUID and the Bluetooth Base.

Example :

- Alert Notification Service UUID (16bit) => 0x1811
- Bluetooth Base UUID (128bit) => 00000000-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB

By combining those two UUIDs, we receive...

- Alert Notification Service UUID (128bit) => 00001811-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB

Is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this:

```
public class BLEUtils {

    public static final long BT_UUID_LOWER_BITS = 0x800000805F9B34FBl;
    public static final long BT_UUID_UPPER_BITS = 0x1000l;
    public static final long BT_CCCD_SHORT_UUID = 0x2902l;
    public static final UUID BT_CCCD_UUID = get16BitBTUUID(BT_CCCD_SHORT_UUID);

    public static UUID get16BitBTUUID(long uuid) {
        return new UUID(BT_UUID_UPPER_BITS + (uuid << 32), BT_UUID_LOWER_BITS);
    }
}
```

Your example looks sane. Is it recognized properly by other devices?

Edit:
The reverse operation requested in the comment would be:

```
public static long getShortUuid(UUID uuid) {
    long result = uuid.getMostSignificantBits();
    result = result - BT_UUID_UPPER_BITS;
    result = result >> 32;
    return result;
}
```

I didn't test it though.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your response !
 But, if I want to extract the "BT_CCCD_SHORT_UUID" from "BT_CCCD_UUID" how can I achieve that?