# How to get the name of the service for the corresponding UUID in bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid

I am developing an Bluetooth application, and i need to get the name of the services provided by a particular client Bluetooth device. I am using the following code to get the UUID's.

**Code Snippet:**

```
 if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_UUID.equals(action)) 
 {
 BluetoothDevice device =       intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
 Parcelable[] uuidExtra =    intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_UUID);
 for (int i = 0; i < uuidExtra.length; i++) {
String abc=uuidExtra[i].toString());
 }
 }
```

I am getting the uuid value as for example "00001000-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB" But i need its corresponding service name like the following.

BrowseGroupDescriptorServiceClassID = 00001001-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB
PublicBrowseGroupServiceClass = 00001002-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB

Answer (score 0):

[On Bluetooth.com](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services) you can find list of 16-bit UUID's. They are all [transformable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36738698/661211) to 128-bit ones You got. You just need to check the GATT spec. The only thing left is just mapping the names with UUID's, which You will probably have to write on your own.

Comment: so you mean that there is no specific syntax to map the names?? @morynicz

Comment: You mean magical built in method for transforming UUID's to human readable strings? I doubt it. But You can check in android documentation.

Answer (score 0):

By the way,it's different from iOS dev,we can't get `service_name` or `charactistics_name` through android public api(except uuid) when connected ,so if 
 we want to extpand ourself `service_name` or `charactistics_name` that outside [blutetooth SIG defined](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/characteristics) in remote bluetooth-hardware. we can't fetch target charactistics_name directly(e.g. `charactistics.getUUIDName()`) (still use mapping add myself charactistics_uuid is not interchangeable)